# Apple devices remotely locked/activation locked via Find my iPhone

Tags: iphone, account-security

This morning I woke up to the alarming fact that my mother's iPhone was put into Lost Mode and had a badly written notice asking to contact *help.apple.us@GMAIL.com*.

I knew it was some form of ransom, but oddly, I have not found anything like it online, just wanted to check if anyone else has heard of this?

Comment: This is not enough information to say anything concrete. Many forms of malware before and after exploitation list a contact for "further assistance" I also see no guarantee here that what you are talking about is ransomware, if it is I would be careful about turning off the phone, maybe doing a backup of info and starting fresh. But why ask for contact if the ransomware is complete, or the exploit is done. More info is necessary.

Comment: There's a difference between 'ransomware' and 'ransom'. If someone broke into the account, they can hold the account for ransom, and that's nothing new. Contact Apple support.

Comment: It appears that others have seen this too: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7973048?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 2):

I also have this exact same problem with the exact email "help.apple.us@gmail.com"

I have paid him 30USD but he won't give me the code. So, DON'T PAY.

The FIRST thing you could do is try the code 9169, this code works for me, why do I know it? I tried 0000-9999 in the efi lock screen.

What happen if the code 9169 is incorrect? Try brute forcing the code in EFI lock (press alt when you boot up, it should have padlock and no cooldown timer). Try from 9000 to 9999 first, then 8000 to 8999. Because I think the code would be more than 7000.

Note: This ransomware happen from a downloaded pirated Photoshop crack from thepiratebay/extra.to

Answer (score 0):

Get in touch with Apple. They can either reset the password of your compromised Apple account (which would allow you to log into Find my iPhone on another computer and unlock yours) or at the very least remove the Activation lock if you show them proof of your ownership of the device (proof of purchase, etc).

To whoever asked another question below (since deleted) - yes, **signing into a compromised iCloud account on a new or unlocked device will allow the attackers to lock your device again**. Make sure your iCloud account is clean (by logging into it - possibly with the help of Apple support to reset the password) and **change the password before logging into it on a Mac or iOS device**.

Answer (score 0):

I received this message on my iphone today. iphone Lost email to help.apple.us@gmail.com.  went to verizon store, they'd never seen so I Had to go to Genius Bar and have phone factory reset. Luckily I had backup on icloud.  I noticed about 4 days prior something weird, had to reset my instagram password 3 times my information in contacts had a different cell number and email entered.  My phone is working now.  Also, I did reset my password on ICLOUD and other accounts.